# HighCharts Tooltip AJAX request onmouseover Event

Tags: highcharts

I am currently using Highcahrts and i need to retrieve my data from an AJAX request, this data should be displayed in the tooltip and i need to send a request as soon as i hover on the series.

I want to display the tooltip when the request ends(i assume that my req is not problematic) so i should i use a promise of course but I don't know what object to attach it a onmouseover event.

I tried looking for it on HC docs and other sources and did not find a thing, hope I could get some help here.

Comment: Sharing some piece of the code will help a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a request in the `mouseOver` event, store data in a point and fnally call the tooltip's `refresh` method. Example:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function() {
                        if (!this.dynamicData) {
                            fetch('https://api.npoint.io/3755b440b66a037c9499')
                                .then(data => data.json())
                                .then(data => {
                                    if (this.state === 'hover') {
                                        this.dynamicData = data;
                                        this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this);
                                    }
                                }).catch(function(error) {
                                    console.log('Request failed', error);
                                });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            if (this.point.dynamicData) {
                return this.point.dynamicData.data;
            }

            return 'Loading...';
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nt2u937m/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Tooltip#refresh